# Low power mode detection in JavaScript for iOS11?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Is there a JavaScript API to detect low power mode for iOS 11 Safari?
I have not found any info on the subject yet.

Answer (score 12):

A workaround to get this done is:

Put a video (hidden) in the webpage with autoplay 'on',
and then detect the 'suspend' event for that video.
Whenever it is invoked, 'power mode is on'.

Here is the script:

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById('ID_of_video');
    videoElement.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
        // suspend invoked
        // show play button
        // iphone is in low power mode
    });

    videoElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
        // video is played
        // remove play button UI
        // iphone is not in low power mode
    });
```

You can also read the explanation here: [Playing video when low power mode is on](https://shaktisinghcheema.com/how-to-autoplay-video-on-mobile-devices-on-low-power-mode/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The suspend event is triggered even without low powered mode turned on. How did you get it to work. I also do not get the play event though the video autoplays.

Comment: I meant it is triggered with both low power mode both on and off.

Comment: @AdityaPS can you share the url or your snippet.

Comment: suspend is emitted always for me

Comment: @DrewBaker did u make sure the video is having: autoplay muted loop playsinline webkit-playsinline

Comment: The suspend event is always triggered when a video is finished downloading. Thats what you are seeing.

Comment: The suspend event is invoked for both , this solution is not up to the mark.

Answer (score 8):

```
.catch((error) => {
  if (error.name === "NotAllowedError") {
     //low power mode
}
```

I struggled with with same concept and one helpful link proved to be this browser check: https://video-dev.github.io/can-autoplay/

result: Video muted (Error "NotAllowedError": The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

So I now have a promise checking if the video is playing, if it is great. Otherwise I catch the NotAllowedError, seems to work ever time.

Answer (score 6):

Safari on iOS **does not support** accessing the status of the low power mode setting (it does not even support [accessing the battery level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949928/is-it-possible-to-access-a-mobile-devices-battery-status-or-charge-via-a-web-bro)).

Comment: Yes I thought that much. Just wanted to be sure. Moreover it seems the battery Status API is already obsolete (unless this is a mistake from MDN): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API

Answer (score 4):

Just like the "suspend" event suggestion, use a hidden video on the with `autoplay loop muted` attrs, then listen to the play event when the video is mounted, like so:

```
testVideo
    .play()
    .then(() => {})
     .catch((error) => {
        //Do something like adding controls to allow user to manually play
    });
});
```

This is the solution as of March 2022, since browsers aren't triggering the suspend event for autoplay cancellation.

Comment: This seems to fire correctly (answer does not, it always fires), but it would be great to get some further explanation as to what is happening here. Thanks

Comment: If you inspect that code on Safari with Low power mode (works on Macs too) you see it throws an "access denied" exception when trying to play the video.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Always throws an error for me on iPhone whether low power mode or no low power mode.

Comment: It works for me if I also add the ```playsinline``` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS 16 Safari, "Low Power Mode" (or say power saving mode) can be detected by checking actual interval of `setInterval`, because cumulative delay [^1] effect happens in Low Power Mode.

For desktop Chromium 109, Energy Saver Mode (or say power saving mode) can be detected by checking frame rate of `requestAnimationFrame`

see online demo:

- [Power Saving Mode detection](https://gist.run/?id=f7b675c7a5bab86dd1488962e646c6cc) (may not work as expected in `<iframe>`)
- [requestAnimationFrame fps detection](https://codepen.io/fuweichin/pen/qBKJYyP?editors=1111)

[^1]: cumulative-delay means actual average interval is obviously greater than given interval

Comment: Tried both of your gists on an iPhone 8 with iOS 16.4. With the battery fully charged, the first solution reports "low power mode? true" whether or not I turn on the low power mode in the settings. The fps detection code shows 28~30 fps regardless of the low power mode. So neither of the solutions worked for me. The low power mode definitely has an effect in terms of video playback - videos refused to autoplay (only) when it's on. I wonder if there's any other solution...

Comment: Thanks for reporting the problem, the detection code doesn't work as expected in Safari in `<iframe>`, so run it in top-level window. There is a threshold constant `1.3` defined in `power-saving.js` which may not applicable for devices other than iPhone 8.

Comment: Works fine in testing, but not in real production site. As soon as the website is loading some heavy resources the ratio gets higher and collecting samples with or without low power mode enabled the numbers get so close it's indistinguishable.
The `1.3` constant is also very dependent on the phone model. On iPhone 6 I need a `2.5` for example.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution (UPDATE 2024)**

1 - Add two elements to your DOM (video and img)

2 - Change CSS of elements, add style: block to your video and style: none to your image

3 - Add a javascript promise, check if onerror device is lower power mode, we remove the video and then change the img style display to block.

Working code bellow:

```
<video src="./public/assets/videos/particles.mp4" id="hero-video" autoplay="true" muted="muted" loop="" disablepictureinpicture="" playsinline=""></video>
<img id="hero-video-fallback" style="display: none;" src="./public/assets/videos/particles_fallback.jpg">
```

The javascript:

```
<script> 
  "use strict"

  var videoElement = document.getElementById('hero-video');
  var videoElementFallback = document.getElementById('hero-video-fallback');
  var promise = videoElement.play();
   
  if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise
      .catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
        if (error.name === "NotAllowedError") {
            console.log("Low Power Mode Active");
            videoElement.remove();
            videoElementFallback.style.display = "block";
          }
        
      })
      .then(() => {
        // if there is no error, then we play the video
        videoElement.play();
      });
  } 
 
</script>
```

You can also hide the video play button and controls completely  just adding some CSS (not working if lower power mode ios, you still need to use javascript for that):

```
 video::-webkit-media-controls {
display: none !important;
opacity: 0;
}
/* Could Use thise as well for Individual Controls */
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {
display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
display: none;
opacity: 1;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button { 
display: none!; 
appearance: none; 
-webkit-appearance: none; 
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
display: none ;
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
display: none;
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-container{
display:none;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0 ;
-webkit-appearance: none ;
} 
:host::shadow::-webkit-media-controls-container{ 
display: none; 
}
```