# Remove video play-button when iOS mode is "lower power"

Tags: html, css

I autoplay my videos and this is working perfect. The only problem is, when a iOS user is on lower power mode the videos are not autoplaying. Then the videos all are covered with the "play-button". Insted i just would like to show the thumbnail without play-button. Is it possible to hide the controls for certain videos on iOS?

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Comment: There are some incorrect answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670150/low-power-mode-detection-in-javascript-for-ios11 but the most recent (March 2022) looks promising.