# check is battery saver is enabled using Angular

Tags: angular, mobile

I am working on an angular application, I need to show images in place of videos when the power saver is enabled on mobile device.
I am looking for an approach which helps me to detect the power sever state of device using angular.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As a hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery

Comment: Yes, I tried with navigator, by this I am able to get the battery charging status but not able to get the status of power saving mode.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was asked: [Low power mode detection in JavaScript for iOS11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670150/low-power-mode-detection-in-javascript-for-ios11)

Tested answer:
Put a video (hidden) in the webpage with autoplay 'on', and then detect the 'suspend' event for that video. Whenever it is invoked, 'power mode is on':

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById('ID_of_video');
    videoElement.addEventListener('suspend', () => {
        // suspend invoked
        // show play button
        // iphone is in low power mode
    });

    videoElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
        // video is played
        // remove play button UI
        // iphone is not in low power mode
    });
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6400815/shakti